# Isuue with Hidden and fixedColumns in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with first 3 columns as fixed and last 2 columns (9th, 10th) are hidden.

```
"columnDefs": [{"targets":[9,10], "searchable":false, "visible":false}]
```

When I initialize datatable for first time it works fine. But on reinitializing Datatable( I am using destroy() before reinit), the columns **do not** remain fixed.
If I remove the above option - "columnDefs" i.e Not keeping last 2 columns as hidden , I am not facing this issue.
Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed is an issue with DataTable I guess. What my solved my problem was not defining the property in options, but hiding it later- after the table is initialized.

```
table.columns([9,10]).visible(false,true);
```